# JNA Array Structure Pointer

Tags: java, structure, jna

I use java to call the .dll,Now I have a structure with a pointer variable "pBuf"in it. I need to convert an array into a pointer and store it in this pointer variable.

**Struct:**

```
public static class NET_DVR_BUF_INFO extends Structure {
   public Pointer pBuf;
   public int nLen;
   @Override
   protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
      return Arrays.asList("pBuf", "nLen");
   }
}
```

***Array:***

```
HCNetSDK.NET_DVR_VIDEOWALLWINDOWPOSITION[] net_dvr_videowallwindowpositions =
                (HCNetSDK.NET_DVR_VIDEOWALLWINDOWPOSITION[]) new  HCNetSDK.NET_DVR_VIDEOWALLWINDOWPOSITION().toArray(windows.size());
```

I need put `net_dvr_videowallwindowpositions` to `pBuf`.

What can i do？

Answer (score 0):

JNA's [Structure](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) class has a `getPointer()` method that returns the pointer to the structure that you need.  Since you have an array of structures, you want the pointer to the first element, index 0:

```
NET_DVR_BUF_INFO bufInfo = new NET_DVR_BUF_INFO();
bufInfo.pBuf = net_dvr_videowallwindowpositions[0].getPointer();
```

Since you defined the array using the Structure's `toArray()` method, the other elements of the array will be in contiguous memory expected on the native side.